# How to dumdata with Django having lazy translation objects defined on the model?

Tags: python, django, unicode

Using [lingua](https://github.com/geomin/django-lingua/blob/master/lingua/translation.py) for translating a model field.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Translation(translation.Translation):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Having this model, dumpdata results in a TypeError:

```
TypeError: <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x104ce5410> is not JSON serializable
```

Is there a way to force unicode on that field before it gets serialized?

==== EDIT ====
Code with traceback:

```
./manage.py dumpdata -v 2 --traceback --natural companies.Country --settings=meyer.settings.local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py", line 117, in handle
    use_natural_keys=use_natural_keys, stream=self.stdout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 99, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 59, in serialize
    self.end_object(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 51, in end_object
    cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, **self.json_kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 408, in _iterencode_dict
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 103, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10e2d9250> is not JSON serializable
[{"pk": 1, "model": "companies.country", "fields": {"name":
```

Output when removing the Translation part:

```
./manage.py dumpdata -v 2 --traceback --natural companies.Country 
[{"pk": 1, "model": "companies.country", "fields": {"name": "Hungary"}}]
```

Comment: As per the info you have given, I don't think that the problem is having anything to do with unicode. Perhaps, you could provide more info about it like a whole verbose of dumpdata, because sometimes, a single line of exception is not enough to debug.

Comment: True, the problem is not the encoding per se but the way translations is made in Django. A name field is becoming a proxy object that is not JSON serializabl. That's what I'd like to force.